# (Blender 2.8 Stable) Smoke Domain renders as cube in EEVEE

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, eevee-render-engine

I imagine this has come up before, and I am happy to have this question deleted (if I cannot do so myself):

When rendering smoke in **EEVEE**, the domain renders, rather than just the smoke. My steps for setting up the scene:

1. Create Domain cube
2. Select starting cube as Flow
3. Save file, then bake Cache.
4. Select Domain and apply Principled Volume material
5. Make sure that Volumetrics lighting effects (Volumetrics Lighting,
   Volumetrics Shadow) are switched on.
6. Switch to Render mode in Viewport to make sure scene results look
   appropriate what is desired.

Render mode shows that scene looks to render smoke appropriately, yet when I choose to make a final Image Render, all I get is the domain cube rather than the smoke.

Am I missing a step? What exactly am I missing?

I have followed multiple different video tutorials, though some are out-dated (including the Volumetrics check-box which no longer appears in the stable release).

[image: Render Mode in Viewport]

[image: Final Rendered Image]

--- Blend File Attachment ---

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZCC-eXvl32SeWA9MIYEjGJSipeoojYF/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

You have a Principled BSDF shader connected to the surface of the domain object. Objects with volumetric materials generally should not have any shader connected to the surface slot. Simply remove the principled BSDF shader, and leave the principled volume shader, and it should work. I [image]

You want your node setup to look like this: 
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay! I must have misunderstood the tutorials I watched. Dunno why I didn't see (or think) that you can only link to the volume output of an object. Thank you, kindly!